# Set a session variable on button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session, google-api-php-client

I'm using the google php api and when I click a button I want to set a session variable so for example I have the following button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-gmail g-signin" id="signinButton" 
data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"
data-clientid="XXXX"
data-redirecturi="postmessage"
data-accesstype="offline"
data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
include_granted_scopes="true"
data-callback="signInCallback">
signin</button>
```

When this button is clicked it calls the signIncallback now I also want it to set a session variable that I can later use to identify what button was clicked so on button click

```
$_SESSION['button'] = 'signin';
```

how would I achieve this or is there an easier way in which I could pass the button id to signInCallback?

Comment: You'll need an AJAX call back to your server - or use `sessionStorage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the suggestions given here I was able to find an answer to my problem.

When I click a button the following code is called

```
$('#signinButton').on('click', function(e){
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'scripts/service.php',
        data: {
            service: name
        }
    }); 
});
```

then the following code in the service.php file

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['service'] = $_POST['service'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just send Ajax request to the page where it will be installed session, and then redirect back